# How to vertically align carousel indicators in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

I don't know how to vertically align the carousel indicators in Bootstrap 5. All the solutions that I'm finding here are for Bootstrap 4, which don't work for me. This is my carousel indicators markup.

```
       <div class='carousel-indicators'>
            <button
                type='button'
                data-bs-target='#carouselExampleIndicators'
                data-bs-slide-to='0'
                class='active'
                aria-current='true'
                aria-label='Slide 1'
            ></button>
            <button
                type='button'
                data-bs-target='#carouselExampleIndicators'
                data-bs-slide-to='1'
                aria-label='Slide 2'
            ></button>
            <button
                type='button'
                data-bs-target='#carouselExampleIndicators'
                data-bs-slide-to='2'
                aria-label='Slide 3'
            ></button>
            <button
                type='button'
                data-bs-target='#carouselExampleIndicators'
                data-bs-slide-to='3'
                aria-label='Slide 4'
            ></button>
        </div>
```

Please keep in mind that I completely copied this code from Bootstrap's documentation itself. I have added some custom CSS to the indicators to make them circles. So, what I'm aiming for is

```
o
o
o
o
```

instead of `o o o o` .

Comment: Is there no CSS involved ? cause i see neither bootstrap classes nor styles here. Maybe add it as a runnable snippet.

Comment: @Raxi These are bootstrap 5 classes. I didn't include the code for the whole carousel. That can be seen here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators

Comment: yea i get that. you'll likely want to set `flex-flow: column nowrap;` and `top: 0;` on your `carousel-indicators`, to get it to cling to the left.

Comment: @Raxi Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The indicators are in a line, because of `display: flex` of the class `carousel-indicators`.

In order to align them vertically, you need to change the `flex-direction` to `column`.

Add the following rule to your code:

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```